# How to return a Promise into a Promise.all(). Promise.all() returning a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My question is easy. The `Promise.all()` method can return a `Promise` ?
Let me explain:

```
function simpleFunction() {
    let queue = [];
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);

    Promise.all(queue)
        .then(() => return Promise.resolve())
        .catch(err => {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        });    
}
```

With this function I want to reject an error if one of the `Promise` of `queue` is rejected.
Actually, I have the ***"unhandle rejection"*** error and I think is because of that. So, I am trying something else.

```
async function simpleFunction() {
    let queue = [];
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);

    try {
        await Promise.all(queue);
        return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
```

After this changement, I have this issue again but I think the second way is correct but I do not why it does not work.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: All of this is unnecessary, just return what `Promose.all` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your

```
return Promise.reject(err);
```

in both snippets. This results in a rejected Promise that the whole thing resolves to, and if that rejection isn't handled anywhere, you'll get an "unhandled rejection" warning.

If the consumer of `simpleFunction` needs to use the Promise, make sure that it also catches it, and make sure to `return` the `Promise.all` call.

There's no need to wrap the `Promise.all` call in a `.then` and `catch`, you can just return the `Promise.all` itself. This will make a Promise which rejects if any of the Promises in the array reject, which is what you want:

```
function simpleFunction() {
    let queue = [];
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);

    return Promise.all(queue);
}
simpleFunction()
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

Or, if the consumer doesn't use the Promise, then `.catch` in `simpleFunction`, but *don't create a rejected Promise*, just handle the error (or ignore it in the `catch`, though that's not a good idea):

```
function simpleFunction() {
    let queue = [];
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);
    queue.push(*PROMISE1*);

    Promise.all(queue)
      .catch((err) => {
        // handle errors here
        // do NOT call `Promise.reject`,
        // because then the rejection will be unhandled
      });
}
```

Comment: So. When all the promise in ```queue```end, the ```Promise.all()``` return a full-field statement ?

Comment: Fulfilled, you mean? Yes, the `Promise.all` will return a Promise which resolves once (if) all Promises in the array resolve. If any of the Promises in the array reject, the `Promise.all` rejects too.